# Creating a sequence of dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, sequence

a quick question.
I want to know if there is a way to create a sequence of data frames, by setting a variable inside the name of a data frame. For example:

```
df_0 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep =',')

b=0
x=1
while (b == 0):
    df_+str(x) = pd.merge(df_+str(x-1) , Source, left_on='R_Key', right_on = 'S_Key', how='inner')

    if Final_+str(x).empty != 'True':
        x = x + 1
    else:
        b = b + 1
```

Now when executed, this returns "can't assign to operator" for **df_+str(x)**. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why not use a list of DataFrames?

Comment: `while (b == 0): dflist.append(pd.merge(dflist[x - 1], Source, left_on='R_Key', right_on = 'S_Key', how='inner'))`

Comment: @user37143 You should upvote the answer in addition to accepting it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right time to use a list (a *sequence* type in Python), so you can refer to exactly as many data frames as you need.

```
dfs = []
dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file1, sep =','))  # It is now dfs[0]

b=0
x=1
while (b == 0):
    dfs.append(pd.merge(dfs[x-1], 
                        Source, left_on='R_Key',
                        right_on = 'S_Key', how='inner'))

    if Final[x].empty != 'True':
        x = x + 1
    else:
        b = b + 1
```

Now, you never define `Final`. You'll need to use the same trick there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but I think a clearer and more logical way is just to create a dictionary with dataframe name strings as keys and your generated dataframes as values?